# How to Copy a list in c#

Tags: c#

I have two lists `check` and `checkBef`.
 `check` is changing her elements , what i want to do is to copy `checkBef` to `check` but `check` has to contains all the elements, i.e: old elements of `checkBef` and the new ones.

```
    List<ListBoxArticle> check = new List<ListBoxArticle>();          
    private void SelectArt_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListBoxArticle> checkBef = LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
        check.Add(checkBef.); //this doesn't work
    }
```

`ListBoxArticle` is a class which contains {string Art, int chap, float somme, bool isChecked}

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please post your code / xaml

Comment: i edit my post @auburg

Comment: checkBef  is a List and check is a List. You can't  paste one list to another with ´Add´. Use ´AddRange´

Comment: @Rekshino may you give me the syntaxe please?

Comment: (1) `checkBef has to contains all the elements` (2) `checkBef = LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true)` Your explanation contradicts your code to a point where I don't know which is correct and which is not. Based on the code, I would say that **LesArticles** contains all the elements, not *checkBef*.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fill it using `List.AddRange`:

```
List<ListBoxArticle> check = new List<ListBoxArticle>();          
private void SelectArt_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    check.AddRange(LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
List<ListBoxArticle> check = new List<ListBoxArticle>();

    private void SelectArt_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      check.AddRange(LesArticles.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true && !check.Contains(x)));

    }
```